# What is my mistake in the counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics

The following problem is from my textbook:

> How many distinct 9-letter strings are possible out of the 17-letter string AAABBCCDEFGHIJKLM?

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi) I've learned about the generating function type of approach and after building the relevant polynomial ([W|A link](http://tinyurl.com/nn43xj4))

$$9!\bigg(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)\bigg(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)^2\bigg(1+x\bigg)^{10}$$

the answer seems to be $898264080$ (the coefficient of $x^9$).

Yet it still felt as a black box so I've decided to do it by hand to make sure I understand.

\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{Type} & \text{Number}  \\
\hline
\text{XXXYYZZ}\square\square & \binom{1}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{10}{2}\frac{9!}{3!2!2!} \\
\text{XXXYY}\square\square\square\square & \binom{1}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{11}{4}\frac{9!}{3!2!} \\
\text{XXX}\square\square\square\square\square\square & \binom{1}{1}\binom{12}{6}\frac{9!}{3!} \\
\text{XXYYZZ}\square\square\square & \binom{3}{3}\binom{10}{3}\frac{9!}{2!2!2!} \\
\text{XXYY}\square\square\square\square\square & \binom{3}{2}\binom{11}{5}\frac{9!}{2!2!} \\
\text{XX}\square\square\square\square\square\square\square & \binom{3}{1}\binom{12}{7}\frac{9!}{2!} \\
\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square & \binom{13}{9}\frac{9!}{1!} \\
\end{array}

So for example the first line means that we have a sting where

- one symbol appears three times (XXX), there is only one candidate
- two symbols appear twice (YY and ZZ), there are only two candidates
- and two more slots are occupied by the symbols which appear once, there are $10$ candidates and we choose $2$

Yet calculating the sum gives another number: $1329365520$ ([W|A link](http://tinyurl.com/p2hjlyn)).

I've checked it as best as I could, so the mistake seems to be conceptual. I'd greatly appreciate if someone alleviates my misunderstanding by pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your code: it should be

> 9!*(c(10,2)/(3!2!2!)+2*c(11,4)/(3!2!)+c(12,6)/3!+c(10,3)/8+3*c(11,5)/4+**3***c(12,7)/2+c(13,9))

Comment: Rebecca, thank you for saving me from sleepless nights.

Comment: No worries.  It's a pity it wasn't a more interesting answer.