# How many 10-character strings can be made having only 4 letters of 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' (16 in total)

Tags: combinatorics

How many 10-character strings can be made having only 4 letters of  'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' (16 in total)

I know how many there are 16-char strings $$ \frac{16!}{4!4!4!4!} $$

How to avoid using multiple case scenario with above technique?  Is there a generic solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: There is no easier way to do it, but you can simplify your work by taking the 16-character string and figuring out how many ways you can REMOVE 6 characters from it and then taking into account inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Could you post how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formula based on generating functions.

coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $10!(1+x +\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!})^4 = 722,400$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi) answer on MSE for why it works.

Comment: This is correct. Thanks for pointing to the link