# Permutations of words from original word.

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many distinct 4-letter arrangements can be made with the letters in the word "PARALLEL"?

My approach:
Because we are only looking at how many different permutations there are and not the *frequency* at which these permutations exist, we can delete the repeated letters and leave only one. This leaves us with the following set of letters: $\{P, A, R, L, E\}$ So $5$ permute $4$ is $120$. It was only then that I realized that deleting repeats will remove words such as $LLLE$  to exist. At this point, I do not know how to add on these possibilities to my approach.

I would appreciate help, and as always, bash me whenever you see a typical blunder of mine.

Comment: I recommend starting with a smaller word, like PALL, then do PAALL.  See how that goes.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, the case approach can be quite error prone, especially for more complex problems:

An alternative approach using generating functions is to find:

coefficient of $x^4$ in $4!(1+x)^3(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}) = 286$

For a detailed explanation of why this works, you can see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi) answer on MSE

Comment: The only "right" approach, IMO.

Comment: @trueblueanil The problem though is how do you actually evaluate a generating function like that? With all those factorials on the denominators of the $x$-terms, it doesn't follow the usual identities for manipulating generating functions. At some point how is this any different than doing it the long way?

Comment: @ArukaJ: If you aren't having  computational help, it is not so good ! But it **is** more mechanical. If you fill up the $4$ slots with the $3$ types, you will find $10$ patterns, $310,301,220,211,202,121,112,103,022,013$, and you should be able to figure out that they will yield $24[1+1+3(\frac12+1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\frac16)+\frac14+\frac16)] = 286$

Comment: Fill up the slots with types? What do you mean? Don't you have to multiply out that huge polynomial?

Comment: @Aruka J: In lieu of multiplying out ! The $3$ types are the letters that are singles $(P,R,E)$, doubles $(A's)$ and triples $(L's). 121$, e.g. represents one from singles, two  from doubles and one from triple. When choosing from singles, you only need to remember to use the appropriate binomial coefficient $\left[\binom31\; here\right],$ and for "multiples" you have to remember to divide by the appropriate factorial $\left[2!\; here\right]$. All said and done, it is still a painful process, but much more mechanical.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few cases:

1. All $4$ letters distinct. There are $\binom{5}{4} = 5$ ways to pick the letters and $4!$ ways to order them.
2. Two letters distinct, one letter repeated twice. Either two A's or two L's. If we have two A's, then we have $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to pick the other letters. $4!$ ways to order them, but divide by $2!$ to account for the doubled letter. Then do the same thing again for the double-L case.
3. Two letters repeated twice. Two A's, two L's. $4!$ ways to order the letters, divide by $2!2!$ to account for the repetitions.
4. One letter by itself, one letter repeated three times. Just the L here. Once we have the triple L, there are $4$ choices for the final letter. $4!$ ways to arrange the letters, divided by $3!$ for the triple L.

$$5 \cdot 4! + \frac{6 \cdot 4! \cdot 2}{2!} + \frac{4!}{2! \cdot 2!} + \frac{4 \cdot 4!}{3!} = 286$$

Comment: Where are the AALL cases?

Comment: Literally just noticed that, already edited to include

Answer (score 1):

Arranging the letters in alphabetical order yields AA E LLL P R. In the four-letter word there may be

- *no repeats*: this has been calculated in the question, and there are 120 words of this form.
- *two of A, the rest distinct*: There are $\binom42=6$ ways to place the A's, and 4 × 3 = 12 ways to place two more letters in the word. This makes 72 ways for this case.
- *two of L, the rest distinct*: this has the same number of words as the previous case (72).
- *two of A and two of L*: Again, 6 ways to place A's, but then there is only one way to place the L's. Hence 6 ways.
- *three of L*: there are $\binom43=4$ ways to place the L's, and 4 possibilities for the remaining letter. This makes 16 ways.

Summing all cases up (which are mutually exclusive and exhaustive) yields 286 4-letter words from PARALLEL.

Answer (score 0):

If you use $j$ A's and $k$ L's, there are $\binom3{4-j-k}$ ways to select the remaining letters, and there are $\frac{4!}{j!k!}$ different ways to arrange the $4$ letters, so in total there are

$$
\sum_{j=0}^2\sum_{k=0}^3\binom3{4-j-k}\frac{4!}{j!k!}=286
$$

admissible words ([Wolfram|Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum%20of%20(sum%20of%20binom%20(3,4-j-k)%20*%204!%20%2F%20(j!%20*%20k!)%20for%20j%3D0..2)%20for%20k%3D0..3) of the double sum).