# To what value does this summation converge: $\sum_{r=o}^{n}{\frac{\binom{n-1}{r}r!}{n^{r+1}}}$

Tags: summation, power-series

I had been trying to solve ([Probability of rolling a 1 before you roll two 2's, three 3's, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2288002/350331)) this problem for quite some while and I think I had found some way ahead but I cant seem to find the closed from for the summation that I ended up on. The summation is:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=o}^{n-1}{\frac{\binom{n-1}{r}r!}{n^{r}}}$$

I also couldn't come up with worthy bounds for which the summation converges to a particular value(although it does converge as discussed in the original post) by the use of squeeze theorem.

Also [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csum%7B(%5Cbinom%7Bn-1%7D%7Br%7Dr!)(n%5E%7B-(r%2B1)%7D)%7D%20r%3D0%20to%20n-1)) gives the sum as

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=o}^{n-1}{\frac{\binom{n-1}{r}r!}{n^{r}}}=\left({\dfrac{e}{n}}\right)^n\Gamma(n,n)$$

**Edit:-**
I dont know how to handle the $\Gamma(n,n)$ and that is what I need help in which I forgot to mention and it also was the whole point of the post.

Comment: As written this is a finite sum which should always converge

Comment: @ThomasGrubb - Edited the post, I had not written it in a very neat manner.

Comment: I suppose a typo; it should be $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=o}^{n-1}{\frac{\binom{n-1}{r}r!}{n^{r}}}=e^n n^{-n} \Gamma (n,n)$$

Comment: So, what is the problem ? The result for any $n$ is a constant, the value of which decreases smoothly when $n$ increases.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I mentioned in the edit what my problem was in the first place which I had totally forgot to mention. Also after reading your answer it seems that I still wouldn't be able to get what the summation would approach as $n\to \infty$

Comment: @user350331. Don't you think that, from my naswer, the wole thing behaves as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2n}}$ for large values of $n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Then, wouldn't this mean that the probability asked in the post that I linked would approach zero

Comment: @user350331. If the initial formula is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comments
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=o}^{n-1}{\frac{\binom{n-1}{r}r!}{n^{r}}}=\left(\frac e n \right)^n \,\Gamma(n,n)$$ If you have a look [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11) (formula $8.11.12$), you will find a series expansion for $\Gamma(n,n)$. Using it, you should get 
$$S_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{1}{ n^{1/2}}}-\frac{1}{3 n}+ \sqrt{\frac{\pi
   }{2}} \frac{1}{12n^{3/2}}-\frac{4}{135 n^2}+
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{288n^{5/2}}+\frac{8}{2835
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{7/2}}\right)$$ which seems to be very accurate even from small values of $n$ as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 1.00000 & 1.00197 \\
 2 & 0.75000 & 0.75020 \\
 3 & 0.62963 & 0.62968 \\
 4 & 0.55469 & 0.55471 \\
 5 & 0.50208 & 0.50209 \\
 6 & 0.46245 & 0.46245 \\
 7 & 0.43116 & 0.43117 \\
 8 & 0.40563 & 0.40563 \\
 9 & 0.38426 & 0.38426 \\
 10 & 0.36602 & 0.36602
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}{{n - 1 \choose r}r! \over n^{r + 1}} & =
\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose r}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{r}\expo{-nt}\,\dd t}^{\ds{r! \over n^{r + 1}}} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nt}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose r}t^{r}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nt}\pars{1 + t}^{n - 1}\,\dd t =
\expo{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{n - 1}\expo{-nt}\,\dd t =
\expo{n}n^{-n}\
\overbrace{\int_{n}^{\infty}t^{n - 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{n,n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{n}\,\Gamma\pars{n,n}}
\end{align}

> The *two arguments* $\ds{\Gamma}$ is the *Incomplete Gamma Function*.