# selecting 4 letters from word BANANA (i am confused between 15 or 30)

Tags: combinatorics

in how many ways 4 letters be selected to form words from the letters BANANA?

Comment: Did you try to use `DictionaryLookup`? Although it seems the dictionary does not know about naan, for example

Comment: Are you looking for `Permutations[Characters["banana"], {4}]`? There are 38 such permutations.

Comment: This is unclear what sort of objects you are explicitly trying to count.  Do you treat $BANA$ as one of the objects you are counting?  Do you treat this the same or different than $NAAB$?  They both have the same collection of letters, just in a different order.

Comment: Assuming order doesn't matter, you can organize your thoughts by listing the outcomes in dictionary order: `AAAB`, `AAAN`, `AABN`, `AANN`, `ABNN`, there are only the five outcomes.  If order does matter, for each of these listed prior you can count the number of arrangements of them, giving $4+4+12+6+12=38$

Comment: I adapted JMoravitz's suggestion here to give a worked example for the more general case of [6-letter combinations from MISSISSIPPI](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4067365/206402), which for your 4-from-BANANA case would take repetition options of (`xxxy`,`xxyy`,`xxyz`), filled in $(2,1,2)$ ways and permuted in $(4,6,12)$ ways for the same answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah you are right here 
correct answer is 5 
here order doesn't matter
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming order doesn't matter, you can organize your thoughts by listing the outcomes in dictionary order: **AAAB**, **AAAN**, **AABN**, **AANN**, **ABNN**, there are only the five outcomes. If order does matter, for each of these listed prior you can count the number of arrangements of them, giving 4+4+12+6+12=38

-@JMmoravitz