# How many different 4-digit numbers can be made with the digits from 12333210?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

> How many different 4-digit numbers can be made with the digits from $12333210$?

**Attempt.** So I've tried splitting into cases:

*Case 1:* Only single letters.

1 2 3 0, except for when 0 is at the first place, so total arrangements minus the arrangements where 0 is in the first place. That is: $$4!-3!$$ (I think)

*Case 2:* One double only.

So either (the "[]" represent the remaining letters for the other 2 places), 1 1 [2,3,0], or 2 2 [1,3,0], or 3 3 [1,2,0]. $$\frac{4P2}{2!}\cdot 3P2\cdot 3-\frac{3P2}{2!}\cdot 2P1\cdot 3$$ the $4P2$ is for the double to be arranged in the any 2 of 4 places, the $3P2$ is the 3 remaining letters to be arranged in the 2 remaining places, and times 3 because we have 3 cases of this as I wrote above, and finally substracting the other term for the arrangements where 0 is in the first place, $3P2$ to arrange the double onto the remaining 3 places, $2P1$ to arrange the remaining 2 letters onto the last space and 3 times due to the 3 cases. And any of the $/2!$ is to account the repeated digits on the doubles.

*Case 3:* 2 doubles?? I'm unsure whether I should compute this because it may be accounted on the 2nd case already

*Case 4:* 1 triple.

The only way to exist a triple is the one such that 3 3 3 [0,1,2], substracting once again the times where 0 is in the first place: $$\frac{4P3}{3!}\cdot 3P1-1$$ $\frac{4P3}{3!}$ on account of the triple to be arranged on the 4 places, $3P1$ for the 3 remaining letters to be arranged at the remaining space and $-1$ on account of the arrangement where 0 is in the first place and followed by 333. Hence my final answer would be to add all these 3 or 4 cases, but I'm unsure if any case arrangement is wrong, if I should account for the 3rd case or not, and if I've managed with the "0 can't be on the first place" correctly by accounting it on each case individually.

*And please, if I have something wrong with my arrangements calculations, please let me know why my thinking is incorrect, I've added the reason to everything I've posted as a result for a reason.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working is correct but you need to count numbers with two doubles separately. It is not counted in case $\small 2$.

Here is an alternate solution before I come to your working.

Count of four digit numbers  $ \displaystyle \small = 3 \cdot (3^3 - 2) + (3^4 - 3 - 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4)  = 137$

Explanation:

First term is four digit numbers with zero. There are $3$ places for zero. Rest of the digits can be any permutations of $1, 2, 3$ with repetition except no triples of $1$ and $2$ (as we have only two $1$'s and $2$'s).

Second term is four digit numbers without zero. All digits have choice of $1, 2, 3$ except that we cannot have any of them $4$ times so we subtract $3$. We also cannot have triples of $1$ or $2$. For each triple, we can have fourth digit from remaining two and they can be in any of the four places. So we subtract $\displaystyle \small 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$.

---

Coming back to your solution:

Case $3$: Two doubles. First choose two doubles from $ \{1, 2, 3\} $ and so count of $4$ digit numbers,

$ = \displaystyle \small {3 \choose 2} \frac{4!}{2!2!} = 18$

Case $1$: All digits are different. Choose one of the three places for $0$ and then remaining $3$ digits can be permuted in $3!$ ways. So count of $4$ digits numbers $\displaystyle \small  = 3 \cdot 3! = 18$

Case $2$: One double. Choose one double from $ \{1, 2, 3 \}$ and then we either have other two digits from rest of $ \{1, 2, 3 \}$ one each or we have one of them along with $0$. So count of $4$ digit numbers,

$ \displaystyle \small  = {3 \choose 2} \cdot \bigg[\frac{4!}{2!} + 2 \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 3!}{2!} \bigg]= 90$

Case $4$: Triple. We have total of $\displaystyle \small 2 \cdot 4 + 3 = 11$ four digit numbers.

That leads to total count of $\displaystyle \small 137$ four digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be also computed from the given digits as

($4$ digit numbers without $0$) + $3\times$($3$ digit numbers with $0$ appropriately inserted )

Thus (coefficient of $x^4 + 3\times$(coefficient of $x^3))\;$ in $(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})^2(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}) = 62+3\cdot25 = 137$

If this method is unknown to you, it is well worth learning, you can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi) for a simple explanation for a well-known prototype.

Answer (score 0):

For $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, let $n_i \ge 0$ be the number of $i$s.  Apply the principle of inclusion-exclusion, where the four properties to be avoided are $n_0 \ge 2, n_1 \ge 3, n_2 \ge 3, n_3 \ge 4$.  Ignoring the properties yields $4^4$ four-digit numbers with digits from $\{0,1,2,3\}$.  If we specify $n_i=k$, we have $\binom{4}{k}$ choices of positions for the $i$s and $3^{4-k}$ ways to populate the remaining $4-k$ positions with $\{0,1,2,3\} \setminus \{i\}$.  The $n_1$ and $n_2$ cases are identical.  No pairs of properties can be satisfied.
Putting it all together, we obtain
$$4^4 - \left(\sum_{k=2}^4 \binom{4}{k}3^{4-k} + 2\sum_{k=3}^4 \binom{4}{k}3^{4-k} + \binom{4}{4}3^{4-4}\right)=162$$
four-digit numbers that might include a leading zero.

To count the cases with leading zero, consider three-digit numbers with digits from $\{1,2,3\}$ that avoid $n_1 \ge 3$ or $n_2 \ge 3$.  Another application of inclusion-exclusion yields
$$3^3 - 2\binom{3}{3}2^{3-3} = 25.$$

So the final count of four-digit numbers with no leading zero is $162-25=137$.