# Subset of a multiset with limited repetition {1,1,1,2,2,2,3} or {3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7,7}

Tags: combinatorics

How to count number of different 3-members-subsets (not ordered) of a multiset {1,1,1,2,2,2,3}? I need a general formula or a general method of solving that problems. Another example: how to count number of defferent 4-members-subsets (not ordered) of a multiset {3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7,7}?

Comment: The general problem is frustrating and the general formula will be *ugly*.  Search long enough on this site and you'll find it.  That said, you can relatively easily craft a formula for a specific scenario that is not fully generalized.  Inclusion-exclusion here in particular is what is going to be useful or generating functions.

Comment: This is half the "anagram" question eg. dealt with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi/4067365#4067365) - "which letters to use" (followed typically by "what order are they in")

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with generating functions.  For the first problem, the answer is the coefficient of $x^3$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^2(1+x)$$
We can take either $0,1,\text{ or }2$ copies of $1$.
Similarly for $2$.
For $3$, we can take either $0$ or $1$ copies.

Comment: very interesting

Comment: better answer than the one in the duplicate thread, for this OP's purposes. why do these threads keep being closed? 'already answered' is clearly different from 'already answered well'

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, thanks you.