# Permutations and Combinations - and repeating letters case

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am having a hard time understanding a simple concept - of arranging alphabets in a word where there are repetitions. Specifically, the part where we divide the number of permutations by the factorial of the repetition.

From the textbook :

In general, repetitions are taken care of by dividing the permutation by the factorial of the number of objects that are identical.

If you look at the word TOOTH, there are 2 O’s in the word. Both O’s are identical, and it does not matter in which order we write these 2 O’s, since they are the same. In other words, if we exchange 'O' for 'O', we still spell TOOTH. The same is true for the T’s, since there are 2 T’s in the word TOOTH as well. In how many ways can we arrange the letters in the word TOOTH?

We must account for the fact that these 2 O’s are identical and that the 2 T’s are identical. We do this using the formula:

nPr/x1!x2!, where x is the number of times a letter is repeated.

My question is why ? Or rather how ?

Why do we divide the total number of permutations by the FACTORIAL of the instances of repeating elements ? I am missing a link in the thought process, so any insight is welcome.

Comment: As an aside, you say `nPr/x1!x2!`.  This sounds dangerously like you think the answer to the question of "How many ways can you arrange 6 letters of MISSISSIPPI" is $\frac{~_{11}P_6}{1!4!4!2!}$ but that is not even an integer and so can not be an answer to a counting question.  The formula you are alluding to is when *all* letters are being arranged.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi?rq=1) for the version where we arrange only a smaller subset of the letters.

Answer (score 3):

In a field of sheep a shepherd has difficulty distinguishing and counting the heads and bodies of the sheep from one another... (*they are too fluffy*) but can clearly see all legs of the sheep and count them.  He knows that every sheep has four legs and so when counting the legs he counted a total of $40$ legs for the sheep.  He knows then that there were exactly $\frac{1}{4}\times 40 = 10$ sheep in his flock.

The "shepherd's principle" is a counting principle which says that if we want to count the number of objects in a scenario and we counted $x$ objects but we had overcounted each object multiple times for a total of exactly $y$ times for each object... then we may correct our count by dividing the total number we had initially counted with repeats by the number of times each object was repeated in our count for a corrected total of $\frac{x}{y}$ *distinct* objects.

Here, if we were to temporarily assume each letter was distinct... like $T_1O_1O_2T_2H$... and arrange those, we will notice that we had overcounted the outcomes.  Specifically, for each relabeling of repeated letters, we will have counted that despite the unlabeled arrangements being otherwise identical.  We divide by the amount we overcounted by, namely $2!\cdot 2!$.

Another explanation... we first choose the positions that the $T$'s occupy simultaneously, followed by the positions the $O$'s occupied, etc... for a total of $\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{3}{2}\times\binom{1}{1}$ which is equal to $\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}$, and in general with non-negative integers $n_1,n_2,\dots ,n_k$ such that $n_1+n_2+\dots+n_k = N$ we have that $\binom{N}{n_1}\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}\binom{N-n_1-n_2}{n_3}\cdots\binom{N-n_1-n_2-\dots-n_{k-1}}{n_k} = \dfrac{N!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots n_k!}$

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I am trying to teach this to a 15 year old so I must admit the sheep example was excellent - conveyed the point across and was easier to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: @VenkiGopal I can't take full credit for that... it was the way it was taught to me.  Looking for references, [I see the phrase used at least as early as 1971](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27958659) and was also used in "*Advanced Combinatorics*" by Louis Comert in 1974... but it is generally considered a fundamental principle so the understanding of it surely spans back centuries and the metaphor of a shepherd likely decades at least.  I'm a bit surprised at the lack of easily found modern references, but I suppose that's a question for hsm.stackexchange (history of science and mathematics)

Comment: It is also referred to as the [Rule of Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_division_(combinatorics)) (*in line with the naming scheme of [Rule of Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum), [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), etc...*)

Comment: One last question - if you could review my phrasing ( again using the sheep metaphor). ..here is what I am thinking ( so I can explain it to my kid)..We know that sheep have 4 legs. So if we count 160 legs in a herd, we can establish that there are 160/4 = 40 sheep. Similarly, "TOOTH" has 2!2! instances ( ?) of duplicates in 1 unique  arrangement. So 5! permutations will have 5!/2!2! unique arrangements. I am struggling with the arrangement/permutation vocabulary - so any clarity on how we can "tie" the sheep analogy to this "TOOTH" example will be really appreciated. Thank you again.