# Select r items from a set with multiplicity k and total items n.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multisets

Let N be a set of n distinct objects having the same multiplicity k. For instance,

```
   N={1,1,2,2,3,3}
```

where n=3 and k=2.

Now I want to select r numbers from this set.

For example if r = 2, then I can select

```
  (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)
```

i.e. there are 9 possible ways.
I was thinking if I can find a formula that computes this.

Links to problems similar to this : [link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144572/permutations-of-a-multiset-having-symbols-with-fixed-multiplicity), [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/permutations-with-identical-objects)

Comment: Sounds like a variant of "red socks, blue socks, green socks"...

Comment: Here the order of selecting r objects is important.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that $(1,2)\ne (2,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes. (a,b) != (b,a)

Comment: So you are looking at maps $[r]\to[n]$ in which no element of the codomain is in the image more than $k$ times. In particular if $k\geq r$ (as in the example) then the result is $n^r$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 1):

If $r/2 < k$ then if you simply consider all $n^r$ combinations of numbers you can form with no restrictions, then the only combinations that will violate your property will have just one number chosen more than $k$ times. You can use simple counting to get a summation formula for how many ways this kind of violation can happen, and subtract from $n^r$ to get your answer. For $k$ asymptotically much smaller than $r$, it seems like a much a harder problem.