# In how many ways can the letters of the word $PATNA$ be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can the letters of the word $PATNA$ be arranged ?

$a)\ 60 \\
 b)\  120 \\
 c)\ 119 \\
 \color{green}{d)\ 59 }\\
$

I thought it would be $\dfrac{5!}{2}=60$ but in book answer is given $59$ which puzzled me

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: Maybe it means, not including P-A-N-T-A?

Comment: For *arranged* it should be $60$. For *rearranged* there would be a case for either $119$ or $59$.

Comment: I think you're right. For the wrong result 59, it probably because the question want you to find how many ways can they be *rearranged* but there is a typo.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: What do u mean by *rearranged* ?

Comment: *Rearrange* means arrange them again but not be duplicated with original case.

Comment: *Changing* the positions of the letters. But the word used in the problem is *arranged*, and then PATNA is a valid arrangement.

Comment: There are 60 combinations, but only 59 of those are rearrangements as 1 of the 60 is the original.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean other ways of arranging the letters. So the result is what you found minus the original word: 59.

Answer (score -1):

The question should be framed as
"In how many ways can it be *rearranged*". Then $59$ would be right.
Otherwise, $60$ is the answer.