# number of strings of $5$ lower case letters $a\cdots z$ that do not contain any letter twice or more

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of strings of $5$ lower case letters $a\cdots z$  that do not contain any letter twice or more?

I think it would be $26*25*24*23*22$  because the first position can be filled in $26$ ways because there are $26$ possible lowercase characters; the second one in $25$ ways and so on

Comment: This looks perfectly good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

Your answer is correct.