# How many permutations of 11 elements are there, from a set of 12 elements with $3$ a's, $3$ b's, $3$ c's, and $3$ d's?

Tags: permutations

> Let $S=\{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d\}$.
> Determine the number of $11$-permutations of the set $S$.

What's the number of ways to take 11 objects from this set S with 12 objects, such that the order of the objects does matter?

I'm not sure if $P(12,11)/(3!)^4$ is the correct approach or not.

Comment: What is an $11$ permutation?

Comment: The number of ways to take 11 objects from the set S such that the order does not matter.

Comment: @Arthur I would interpret it as "*How many length 11 strings exist using 0-3 a's, 0-3 b's, 0-3 c's and 0-3 d's.*"  An interesting thing to note about this specific situation is that you can find a nice bijection to an easier problem: that of the one where you actually arrange all twelve characters and cross through the last appearing one.

Comment: @JustinStevenson you mean where order *does* matter.  Notice further that $P(12,11) = \frac{12!}{(12-11)!}=\frac{12!}{1!}=12!$, so your proposed answer is in fact equal to $\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}$ and is correct, but probably for the wrong reasons.  If you were to try to answer the question of how many 2-permutations following your proposed formula, I expect you will get a number which is not even an integer.

Comment: Ah yes I did mean where order does matter, and if using P(12,11) isn't the correct approach what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Brute force can handle most small cases and is probably the easiest approach for small cases.  By brute force, I mean, break into cases for what the unused letters are.  For larger problems, it becomes a very difficult problem.,  For example, "How many 100 permutations of {30*a, 30*b, 30*c, 30*d}" I would not want to do.  Read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/permutations-with-identical-objects?rq=1) for the start of more general techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right answer, but for the wrong reason :)

The set only has $11$ objects, so in order to take $11$ of them, we have to just choose $1$ to not take. So here are the possibilities for the $11$ objects we can take:

- Everything except 1 $a$: $\{a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d\}$
- Everything except 1 $b$: $\{a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d\}$
- Everything except 1 $c$: $\{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,d,d,d\}$
- Everything except 1 $d$: $\{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d\}$

In each of the 4 cases, the number of ways of arranging the 11 objects will be
$$
\frac{11!}{3!3!3!2!}.
$$
Note that the 2! is not a typo: one of a, b, c, d only appears 2 times (rather than 3) in a set of 11.
Therefore, since there are $4$ cases in the list above, the total number of possibilities is
$$
4 \cdot \frac{11!}{3!3!3!2!}
= \underbrace{\frac{12!}{(3!)^4}}_{\text{Your answer}}
= 369600.
$$

#### Quicker way

A quicker way is described in the comments and other answer: you can first notice that the number of ways to list out 11 objects is the same as the number of ways to list out 12. Then you are just counting the number of ways to arrange 12 objects where 4 sets of 3 are repeated.

Comment: Is 2! a typo in your last line? Shouldn't 2! be 3!? Because a, b, c, d each exist thrice in S?

Comment: @PGTK It's not a typo: one of a, b, c, d only exists twice in a set of 11 elements of S. I have updated the answer to clarify that.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer! can you please clarify the 4 at the front of $4 \cdot \frac{11!}{3!3!3!2!}$? Why multiply by 4?

Comment: Pls edit your answer, rather than comment? Comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Every 11-permutation of S corresponds uniquely to a permutation of S,
by inserting the missing element of the 11-permutation at the end.

(For example, $\;\;acbdacbddab\longleftrightarrow acbdacbddabc$)

Therefore the number of 11-permutations of S is the same as the number of permutations of S:

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle \binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}=\frac{12!}{(3!)^4}$

Comment: Please it how you choosing 3 element form 12

Comment: 3 element from 9 elements and 3 element form 6 elements and applying multiplication rule