# How many permutations of the letters A to H if the three letters ABC must appear together but not necessarily consecutively?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations

How many permutations of the letters A to H exist if the three letters ABC must appear together but not necessarily consecutively?

Pretty confused on how to start... 
Can I group ABC as one letter? Then there will be 6 "letters", making it 6!, and then multiplied by 3! because there are 3! ways in which ABC can be assigned.

Comment: if "must appear together" mean they must be in $3$ consecutive positions, and "not necessarily consecutively" means not necessarily in alphabetical order, then your answer $6! \times 3!$ is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a good strategy.  The trickiest part of combinatorics is figuring out to describe a complicated situation in ways that are relatively easy to count.  That's what you did here -- you want to arrange the "letters"  ABC, D, E, F, G, H into words, which can be done in 6! ways, and then you can arrange the block ABC in 3! ways for a total of 6!3! = 4320 arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

$A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$

$ABC$ always appear together. Consider this as a single letter X.

$X,D,E,F,G,H$

Number of permutation=$6!$=$720$

The number of permutation in X is also $3!$.

Therefore total permutations=$6! \times 3!$=$720 \times 6$=$4320$