# Permutation with repetition, more elements than slots to choose from

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Using 3 A's, 5 B's, 7 C's, how many 4-letter word can you arrange them into? Note that here 3+5+7>4.

We can't use the formula: $\frac{n!}{p!q! \cdots}$ because $\frac{4!}{3!4!7!}$ will be a fraction.

What is the general formula for this type of problem?

Comment: Please edit to include your effort.  Note that in this case you can almost ignore the limited supplies...indeed, there's only one word that you can't make because of the restrictions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to answer this question would be to consider how many 4 letter words contain a certain number of A's.

For words containing 3 A's, there are two choices for the final letter, and 4 different reorderings, so 8 such words.

For words containing 2 A's , we can take the final two letters as 4 ordered choices, and then there are 6 ways of reordering the A's, so 24 such possibilities.

For words containing 1 A, there are 8 ordered choices for the final three letters, and 4 different choices for the position of A. So 32 choices.

And for words containing 0 A's , there are 16 ordered choices for the final four letters.

So overall, 8+24+32+16=80 words

A much nicer way to see this is that you can make all the words you would be able to make without the restriction apart from AAAA , so if you could use every letter as many times as you would like, then there would be 3^4=81 possible ways to form words. As you can't use AAAA, take away one , and you get 80.

Answer (score 2):

J.Dmaths has already explained how you can solve such a question.

The only thing I would add is that you can't use the formula $\frac{n!}{p!q!r! \cdots}$ $\big [$ as you have, $\frac{4!}{3!4!7!}$ $\big ]$ because $n$ must be the total number of elements ($p+q+r + \cdots$). That is not the case here, and so you end up with a fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a general way to count labeled enumeration problems: use exponential generating functions.

If a word has $a$ As, $b$ Bs, and $c$ Cs, then the number of permutations that can be formed is
$$\frac{4!}{a!b!c!}$$

Then we can use counting combinations similar to ordinary generating functions: for $a \le 3$, find the coefficient of $x^4/4!$ in

$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac {x^1} {1!}  + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}  \right)}_{\text{select } a} \underbrace{\left(\frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac {x^1} {1!}  + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots \right)^2 }_{\text{select } b,c} = \left(1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 \right) e^{2x}$$

(Since $b$ and $c$ are effectively unlimited, we can use the EGF of $e^x$)

P.S. I think for extremely large polynomials, FFT polynomial multiplication can be used, but obviously that isn't needed here.