# Counting $r$-permutations of a multiset

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Given a multiset $ S = \{\!\!\{ m \cdot 0, 1, ..., n \}\!\!\}$ where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, find the number of $m$-permutations of $S$.

For example, when $m=2$ and $n=2$, $S = \{\!\!\{ 0, 0, 1, 2 \}\!\!\}$ and the $2$-permutations are: $$ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)$$

Similar questions have been asked before ([[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/permutations-of-subsets-of-a-multiset) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395657/on-counting-and-generating-all-k-permutations-of-a-multiset)), but no correct or concise close form solution was given in either case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use lower-case for the natural numbers here: $S=\{\!\!\{m\cdot0,1,2,\ldots,n\}\!\!\}$. As usual let $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Suppose that $0\le k\le m$; we’ll count the $m$-permutations of $S$ with $k$ zeroes. There are $\binom{m}k$ ways to choose the positions of the zeroes and $(m-k)!\binom{n}{m-k}$ ways to fill the remaining $m-k$ positions with an $(m-k)$-permutation of $[n]$, so there are

$$(m-k)!\binom{m}k\binom{n}{m-k}=(m-k)!\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{n}{n-(m-k)}$$

$m$-permutations of $S$ with $k$ zeroes. Thus, there are altogether

$$\sum_{k=0}^m(m-k)!\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{n}{n-(m-k)}=\sum_{k=0}^mk!\binom{m}k\binom{n}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^mk!\binom{m}k\binom{n}k$$

$m$-permutations of $S$. I don’t at the moment see any nice simplification of this sum.

Comment: Thank you for both the advice and help, I have edited the original post on your suggestion.

Comment: @SCJ: You’re welcome