# Number of distinct dodecahedra given a multiset of edge colors. Burnside's lemma.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Given a multiset of colored edges $A$, $|A| = 30$ I want to know the number of distinct dodecahedra that can be constructed using these edges. Two dodecahedra are equal if one of them is a rotation of another dodecahedron.

By labeling colors with numbers $n$, $n \in \{1,...,30\}$ I can give the following multisets as an example:

1. For $A = \{1,...,1\}$ or $A = \{1, 2,...,2\}$ the answer is obviously $1$.
2. For $A = \{1, 1, 2,...,2\}$ it is $11$.

This problem should probably be solved using Burnside's lemma.

To start with, here is the description of dodecahedron's [symmetry group](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/geometry/Lectures/L10.html).

There are $24$ rotations that fix $6$ edges, $20$ ones that fix $10$, $15$ rotations fixing $16$ edges each and one rotation fixing all $30$ edges.

Therefore, by Burnside's lemma the answer should be $\frac{1}{60}(a_1 + 24a_2 + 20a_3 + 15a_4)$ where $60$ is the order of $A_5$. I also found [OEIS A282670](http://oeis.org/A282670) number of ways to color edges of a dodecahedron with at most $n$ colors.

The problem is that I don't know what these $a_i$ should be (and I'm actually not sure the answer should look like that at all). My best guess for that $a_1$ is the permutation of a multiset (for the second example it would be the case $a_1 = \frac{30!}{2!28!}$ ) and remaining $a_i$ would be k-permutations of a multiset for which I failed to find an explicit formula (this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395657/on-counting-and-generating-all-k-permutations-of-a-multiset?noredirect=1&lq=1) has an example of such permutations), where $k$ would be the number of edges fixed by a rotation.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following        the        approach        at        this        [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380807/) we compute the
cycle index of the permutation group of the edges.  Using the image at
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron) we see
that there are three types of  symmetries in addition to the identity:
rotations about  an axis passing  through the centers of  two opposite
faces, rotations about  an axis passing through  opposite vertices and
$180$ degree rotations that flip two opposite edges, mapping each onto
itself.

The identity contributes the following term to the cycle index:
$$ a_1^{30}.$$

There are six  pairs of opposite faces and four  rotations for each of
these about an axis passing through the centers of the pair which turn
everything into five-cycles since the faces other than the chosen pair
also form five-cycles, which applied to the edges gives

$$ 6 \times 4 \times a_5^6 = 24 a_5^6.$$

There are  ten pairs of opposite  vertices and two rotations  by $120$
and $240$ degrees  for each of these which create  two three-cycles at
the two vertices. The two  rotations create two three-cycles among the
faces not  adjacent to the two  vertices and this carries  over to the
edges of  these faces (the remaining  six faces not incident  with the
pair share  one and two  edges with the  three faces incident  at each
vertex of the pair and the rotation preserves this property), giving

$$ 10 \times 2 \times a_3^{10}.$$

There  are  fifteen pairs  of  opposite  edges  and the  $180$  degree
rotations about  the plane  passing through them  fix those  edges and
partition everything else into two-cycles, giving

$$ 15 \times a_1^2 a_2^{14}.$$

It follows  that the cycle index  of the permutation group  $G$ of the
edges is

$$ Z(G) = \frac{1}{60}
\left( a_1^{30} + 24 a_5^6 + 20 a_3^{10} + 15 a_1^2 a_2^{14}\right).$$

Substituting into the  cycle index we obtain the  explicit formula for
$N$ colors

$$\frac{1}{60} \left(N^{30} + 24 N^6 + 20 N^{10} + 15 N^{16}\right)
= \frac{1}{60} N^{30} + \frac{2}{5} N^6
+ \frac{1}{3} N^{10} + \frac{1}{4} N^{16}.$$

We obtain the sequence

$$1, 17912448, 3431529649899, 19215359484207104,
\\ 15522042948408209375, \ldots $$

which points us to [OEIS A282670](https://oeis.org/A282670)
where these data are confirmed.

Next suppose  we have $q$ different  colors and a multiset  drawn from
these  colors and  we  ask  about the  number of  colorings with  this
multiset. We use the Polya Enumeration Theorem, which yields

$$ Z(G)(A_1+\cdots +A_q) = \\ \frac{1}{60}
\left( (A_1+\cdots +A_q)^{30}
+ 24 (A_1^5+\cdots +A_q^5)^6
+ 20 (A_1^3+\cdots +A_q^3)^{10}
\\ + 15 (A_1+\cdots +A_q)^2 (A_1^2+\cdots +A_q^2)^{14}\right).$$

E.g.  for two  colors  with  one color  appearing  twice  we need  the
coefficient on $[A_1^2 A_2^{28}].$ We get

$$\frac{1}{60} \left(  {30\choose 2}
+ 15 + 15 {14\choose 1} \right) = 11$$

as claimed. As a concluding observation we also obtain for
colorings with exactly $M$ colors  the closed form

$$\frac{M!}{60} \left({30\brace M}
+ 24 {6\brace M}
+ 20 {10\brace M}
+ 15 {16\brace M}\right).$$

This  yields a  finite  sequence  from $M=1$  to  $M=30$ (the  maximum
possible with all edges different)

$$1, 17912446, 3431475912558, 19201633473082192,
15426000466104548370, \ldots, 1879979643918904128084836352000000,
\\ 438404032189593555246120960000000, 64102774454612839170441216000000,
\\ 4420880996869850977271808000000.$$

We see in the second term that the two  monochrome colorings have been
subtracted and the last one is $30!/60$ (with all edges unique we have
that all orbits are the same size).

Comment: The answer is just brilliant, it took me a while to process it though.