# Put $N$ identical balls into $m$ different buckets, each bucket has at least one ball, how many ways?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $N>m$, denote the number of ways to be $W(N,m)$

#### First method

Take $m$ balls out of $N$, put one ball at each bucket. Then every ball of the left the $N-m$ balls can be freely put into $m$ bucket. Thus we have: $W(N,m)=m^{N-m}$.

#### Second method

When we are going to put $N$-th ball, we are facing two possibilities:

1. the previous $N-1$ balls have already satisfies the condition we required, i.e. each of $m$ buckets has at least one ball. Therefore, we can put the $N$-th ball into any bucket.
2. the previous $N-1$ balls have made $m-1$ buckets satisfies the condition, we are left with one empty bucket, the $N$-th ball must be put into that empty bucket. However, that empty bucket may be any one of the $m$ buckets.

Therefore, we have the recursion formula:

$$
W(N,m) = m W(N-1,m) + m W(N-1,m-1)
$$

**It is obvious that the two methods are not identical, which one has flaws?** I would like to know which part of the reasoning is wrong and I would also want to hear about the case when the balls are distinct.

Comment: Why would there be an empty bucket for the N-th ball ?

Comment: That is a possible situation before putting $N$-th ball

Comment: But then there could also be 2 empty buckets, or 3 empty buckets ... couldn't there ?

Comment: @Astyx you can't fill two empty buckets with a single ball.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the explicit formula for Permutations of Subsets of a Multiset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/whats-the-explicit-formula-for-permutations-of-subsets-of-a-multiset)

Comment: @user35395 Again, this is not a duplicate, not even close. Please stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First put $1$ ball into each of $m$ buckets.

Then you are left with $N-m$ balls.

Use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method. Arrange the remaining balls in a row.  Add $m-1$ dividers. Compute number of ways to arrange the balls and dividers.

Number of ways is given by =$$\binom {(N-m)+(m-1)}{m-1}=\binom{N-1}{m-1}$$

Comment: you mean first is wrong?

Comment: That would appear to be the case. Try it for a small number, e.g. $N=5, m=3$ and see.

Comment: Yes both methods are wrong

Comment: @Astyx Do you really mean that? Does any one survive if the balls are distinct? If you can write a detailed answer about that, it would be great.

Comment: @fizis: If the balls are distinct, then the number of possible arrangements would be a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @Edward Then both the two methods still can't survive?

Comment: @fizis: Both equations would still be incorrect if the balls are distinct.

Comment: @Edward It seems that if the balls and the bucket are both distinct, String number of the second kind is not we are looking for...

Comment: I think there's a typo, and it should read $\binom{(N-m)+m-1}{m-1}$.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the final answer is $\binom{N}{m}\binom{N-1}{m-1}$, yes?  I am thinking this is because there are many ways to pick 1 ball for each bucket.

Comment: @Addem Yes, thanks. Typo corrected.

Comment: Wait, now there's another typo, the $m$s should cancel on the right-hand side.  :)

Comment: @Addem - haha it's ok now.

Answer (score 3):

**hypergeometric** has given a good analysis of the problem for indistinguishable balls.

When the balls are distinct, we can number them $1$ through $N$. If we number the buckets $1$ through $m$, each assignment of balls to buckets with at least one ball in each bucket can be thought of as a function from the set $[N]=\{1,\ldots,N\}$ **onto** the set $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$. That is, we’re counting the surjections from $[N]$ to $[m]$.

The [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) are the key ingredient here: the Stirling number ${N\brace m}$ is the number of partitions of $[N]$ into $m$ non-empty parts. There are $m!$ ways to assign each of the parts to one of the $m$ numbers in $[m]$, so there are $m!{N\brace m}$ surjections from $[N]$ to $[m]$ and hence the same number of allowable assignments of the labelled balls to the labelled buckets. It turns out that

$$m!{N\brace m}=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}\binom{m}kk^N\;,$$

a result that can also be obtained directly using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement). There is no really nice closed form for this number, though the Stirling numbers themselves do satisfy a fairly nice recurrence:

$${{n+1}\brace k}=k{n\brace k}+{n\brace{k-1}}\;,$$

with ${0\brace 0}=1$ and ${n\brace 0}={0\brace n}=0$ for $n>0$.

Comment: How can we have the summation formula from the recursion formula?

Comment: @fizis: That isn't how I would get it; the inclusion-exclusion argument is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Alright, I will look into it.

Comment: Thank you - very kind of you  :) Nice answer, extending this to distinct balls. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake comes form the fact that the two possibilities of the second method are not disjoint.

For instance when putting the 6-th ball in a set of three buckets, if you have $(1,2,2)$ you can get $(2,2,2)$, or $(1,3,2)$ or $(1,2,3)$.

If you had $(0, 3, 2)$ you need to get $(1,3,2)$ which is a way that has already been counted in the previous case.

Comment: you mean second is wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean