# Choose 8 with at least 3 of each

Tags: combinatorics

> A cerntain men's club has sixty members; thirty are business men and thirty are professors.  In how many ways can a committee of eight be selected if at least three must be business men and at least three professors?

I have the solution to this.  The way they did it is to add up the cases in which you have 3 professors and 4 professors and 5 professors to get $$2{30 \choose 3}{30 \choose 5} + {30 \choose 4}^2$$

I understand that answer, but I thought about it a different way.  My thought process was that there should be 3 that definitely have to be professors and there are ${30 \choose 3}$ ways to select them.  There are also 3 that definitely have to be business men and there are ${30 \choose 3}$ ways to select these guys as well.  There are two positions left and they must come from the remaining 54 members so I get a total of $${30 \choose 3}^2{54 \choose 2}$$ ways of arranging the 8.  Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Because you've multiple-counted some of the combinations.  Let's just focus on the professors, which we'll call A through Z.  If the eventual selection contains professors A, B, D, E, G, then you'll count that combination $10$ times: once when your first three are A, B, D; once when they're A, B, E; once when they're A, B, G; once when they're A, D, E; and so on.  Same with the businessmen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the explicit formula for Permutations of Subsets of a Multiset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/whats-the-explicit-formula-for-permutations-of-subsets-of-a-multiset)

Comment: @user35395 That is not even close to being a duplicate. Please stop flagging these questions, you are not being helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You are over counting.

Long answer:

$\binom {30}3^2\binom{54}{2}$ counts ways to select 2 from 30 business men and 2 from 30 professors into subgroup A, and any 2 from the remaining 52 personages in subgroup B.  Which is okay if the committee is so divided, but it is not.

Selecting professors {Adam, Ben, Carl}, then {Donna}, or {Adam, Ben, Donna} then {Carl}, and so on, result in the same committee and should not be counted four times over.  Similarly for selecting business men.